# How to get rid of possibly superfluous function constraints?

Tags: haskell

Let's us have two classes without any methods, the other being a sub-class. 
Further, let's assume functions `f5` and `f6` that do `unsafeCoerce` from type to other.

Now, ghci can compose those functions and find their signatures (with the help of ScopedTypeVariables), see `f56, f56b and f56'` below. 
These are essentially functions having constraint `Hmm`.

1. Is it possible to write `f56c`, that is, write it without
   referring to class `SHmm` in the constraints? E.g. can ghci compile this 
   with the help of some language-pragma?
2. What kind of danger there is in using `unsafeCoerce` when the
   classes don't have any methods? (Or when the sub-class `SHmm`
   doesn't have any methods?) Is there other way / recommended way to
   write `f5` and `f6`?

And as a last one, in the code below `f5` and `f6` have their signatures so why it is not possible to just write `f56 = f5 . f6`? (Especially in the case when `SHmm` is empty, which is the reason it is so easy to think that constraint `SHmm` is not needed when writing `f56`.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce

class Hmm (f :: *)
class Hmm f => SHmm f

f5 :: (Hmm m1, SHmm m) => m -> m1
f5 = unsafeCoerce

f6 :: (Hmm m, SHmm m1) => m -> m1
f6 = unsafeCoerce

f56 :: forall m1 m2 m3. (Hmm m3, Hmm m2, SHmm m1) => m3 -> m2
f56 = f5 . (f6 :: m3 -> m1)

f56b :: forall m1 m2. (Hmm m2, SHmm m1) => m2 -> m2
f56b = f5 . (f6 :: m2 -> m1)

-- f56c :: forall m2. Hmm m2 => m2 -> m2
-- f56c = f5 . (f6 :: SHmm m1 => m2 -> m1)

f56' :: forall m1 m2 m3. (Hmm m3, Hmm m2, SHmm m1) => m3 -> m2
f56' a = f5 $ (f6 :: m3 -> m1) a
```

Comment: Why this fascination with `unsafe` stuff? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: As others have said, none of this really makes much sense. You may find it interesting to check out the `Coercible` pseudo-class in `Data.Coerce`; that's some fairly powerful coercion machinery. There are some additional tools for working with it in `Data.Type.Coercion`. Note also `coerce`-related rewrite rules; the `containers` package has several good examples I wrote a few years ago. Unsafe coercions can (unfortunately) be useful with some type family-based constraints and also with rewrite rules that erase proofs.

Comment: I'm trying to re-organize a lib's interface having many similar functions. I'd like it to follow a bit more closely the spec and at the same time touch the surface as little as possible. (It might well be that the interface is best left intact.) I'm actually relieved for the clear answer to not use unsafe-stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***absolutely not** a safe use* of `unsafeCoerce`. Basically, `f5` can by signature convert any two types into one another, provided each of them has an instance of certain classes. But knowing that doesn't tell you anything about the relation *between* the types `m` and `m1`. The only way this could be safe is if there is only one type with a `Hmm` instance – say, `Int` – because then it would effectively be just

```
f5 :: (m1 ~ Int, m ~ Int) => m -> m1
```

aka

```
f5 :: Int -> Int
f5 = unsafeCoerce
```

...and that's in fact guaranteed to work, albeit obviously not very useful. But as soon as you add any other instance, say, `SHmm String`, you get a complete bogus “conversion function” between `Int` and `String`.

Whether the classes `Hmm` and `SHmm` have any methods is irrelevant here, unless it's methods that only a type isomorphic to [`Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Void.html#t:Void) can ever fulfill (in which case all these functions are safe, but also completely absurd).

So, as `f5` and `f6` don't work to begin with, I don't know what to answer to the rest. I fail to see how any of this makes sense even on a conceptual level.

Comment: ok, this helps me to close one path. I'm still trying out different ways to "classify a function set" (you answered a q couple of days ago that is related).